how to apply css without using encapsulation:viewEncapsulation.none?
I'm fairly new to angular but for some reason I can't find the reason why css isn't applied on my html unless I use encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in home.component.ts, I was trying the second tutorial of angular, the home one.
this is my home.component.ts
import { encapsulateStyle } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.css',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent {}


and I put in the css

body {
    background-color: #007bff;
}

see the thing it doesn't work if I take off encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None and if I'm not mistaking, it will apply that css everywhere right ?
I tried searching on the internet and on stackoverflow question but didn't find anything

Styles for the component should be put into the component's CSS file. Global styles should be put in the styles.css file. The body element is not part of any Angular component. This is why you need to put body styles into the styles.css file.
More information about this file can be found in the file structure docs.

The way Angular manage the .css (to isolate the .css of each element) is adding a prefix in .css.
Imagine a component like
template:`<div class="testContainer">
             <p>Created in HTML</p>
          </div>`,
styles:[`
   p{
      color: red;
    }
`]

If you check the .html create using F12 you see some like
<div _ngcontent-ng-c474887881="" class="testContainer">
   <p _ngcontent-ng-c474887881="">Created in HTML</p>
</div>

If you check the .css, you see some like
p[_ngcontent-ng-c474887881] {
  color: red;
}

(the _ng-content-ng-c474887881] can be another one, it's only to explain me.
This is the reason that if you don't use ViewEncapsulation.None (And really use it's a very, very bad idea)
body{
  background-color: #007bff;
}

Is "translate" as
body[_ngcontent-ng-c474885780]{
  background-color: #007bff;
}

And you have not a body with an attribute "_ngcontent-ng-c474885780"

CSS selectors in angular components are shimmed by default.
This means they are altered to only match the HTML inside the component (and no leak outside).
When you set ViewEncapsulation.None, you're telling angular that it is fine to leak the CSS to the outside.
If you want to style something globaly, like body, you should put it in your global styles, outside components.

I suspect that you component does not contain a body tag. Your css selector does select a body tag tho.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
